# Why my second rest request in angular can't update the datagrid?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm working on an Angular application, but I'm in trouble with the update of the datas.

1- I'm creating a datagrid
2- I'm requesting to get the data from a specific user
3- I'm requesting to get the name of a department by it's uuid (contained in the previous request) : informatique
4- Datagrid is updated

When I modified the name of department without a rest request, the name is updated. But, when, in the same location in the code, I replace this by the request, the datagrid is not well updated. (but the result is well recepted)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.context = { componentParent: this };
    this.subscription.push(this.translate.get('Purchase').subscribe((res) => {
        this.gridOptions.onGridReady = (params) => {
            this.gridApi = params.api;
            this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(this.createColumnDef());
            this.gridApi.refreshCells({ force: true });
            this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        }
        // Limit Purchases to user budgetscope matches
        this.userService.getUserInfo().subscribe((user) => {
           this.subscription.push(this.purchase.findByUserId(user.id).subscribe((purchases: PurchaseOrder[]) => {
                this.rowData = purchases;

                //change the uuid of the department by it's name
                this.rowData.forEach(element => {
                    console.log('1');
                    let mafonction = (element) => {
                        this.departmentService.findByDepartmentUuid(element.department).subscribe((department: Department) => {
                            element.departement = department.name;
                            console.log(element.departement);
                        });
                    };
                    mafonction(element);
                });
                console.log('2');
            }))
        }),
        () => {
            // ...
        };
    }));
    console.log('4');
}
```

When I'm executing this code, I got, in the console :

> 1
>   2
>   informatique

but no name in the datagrid.

When I just replace :

```
this.rowData.forEach(element => {
    console.log('1');
    // ...
    mafonction(element);
});
```

by

```
this.rowData.forEach(element => {element.department = "nothing2"});
```

'nothing2' is displayed in the datagrid.

Comment: Where does the "Informatique" come from? Could it be that your `findByDepartmentUUID` does not yield a `Department` but a string? In that case `department.name` would be undefined.

Comment: Hi ! thank you for your answer. findByDepartementUUID return an observable Department. It contain "informatique" in .name, because,when I displayed it via console.log, it's well displayed.

Comment: I guess it's related to your naming of the variables. You have an outer `element` of your `forEach` loop and an inner `element` within `mafonction`

Comment: Yes, it's the same, because I want it. I take the uuid in element.departement, and then, replace it by the name. We can see  it's the good one, because I can access to the other values.

Comment: I think it's a problem of synchronization of the two observables.
And the datagrid is initialised with the first observable, but, when the second has received datas, the datagris is not editable anymore. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue : this.rowData = purchases; should have put in the last block (department.findByUuid), in order to display the last datas.